# Clicking on a selected link without using the mouse, using Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Let's say I made have some link selected in my browser (for instance, if I do a CTRL + F and type "Questions", selecting the Questions tab on the top of this page).

I'd like to know if there's any way to click in the selected link without having to do it with my mouse.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with the Return key, so Ctrl-F, type the text of the URL, then hit escape.  The focus should remain on the link you had highlighted.  Hitting Return will open the link.

Comment: ... or the Space key. :)

Comment: @iglvzx Yes!  Only I prefer the Return key, as you can use Ctrl-Return to open a new tab for the link, whereas this doesn't seem to work with the space bar.

Comment: If you know you're searching for a link, press the apostrophe-key to enter the links-only quicksearch. Unlike the regular quicksearch it matches nothing but hyperlinks, and pressing enter will immediately open the current selection.

Answer (score 8):

Use the apostrophe-key ' to enter Quick find (links only) mode.

Maybe also useful: F6 to move the keyboard focus (hard to explain, just try it out).

http://www.accessfirefox.org/Firefox_Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts.html

Comment: And use F3 / shift+F3 for next / previous search result in quick find mode too.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to find how to open link during searching without touching mouse.
Solution provided by Paul works fine. If you want to make it even faster then install Auto Hotkey https://autohotkey.com/

And here I’ve written short script which opens searched link when you press Shift+Enter.

Version with opening link in new tab

```
; ==== #Firefox - Essential Firefox shortcut to open searched link / keyword - Open link in new tab ====
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTitleMatchMode, Fast
#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
Shift & Enter::
    Send {ESC}{Ctrl Down}{Enter}{Ctrl Up}
Return
```

Version with opening link in current tab

```
; ===== ;#Firefox - Essential Firefox shortcut to open searched link / keyword - Open link in current tab ====
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetTitleMatchMode, Fast
#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
Shift & Enter::
    Send {ESC}{Enter}
Return
```

Answer (score -1):

I see that it has been 5 years since you asked this question.  Instead of searching for a word with Ctrl + F, I do the following:  I have my "mouse keys" turned on and I use my keypad (with "Num Lock" on) to navigate my pointer to the word or image link.  When the pointer becomes the "hand", then on my keypad, I first press / (forward slash) and then I press 5.  (There is no need to press and hold down the / key.  Just press and release it.  Pressing the / key moves the focus to the word or image.)  Then press the 5 on the keypad, and the link opens.  I discovered this option through much trial and error.  I wanted to find a way to be able to select any "clickable" item without using my mouse.  Initially, I tried using the regular forward slash on my keyboard with the 5 on the keypad, but it did not work.  [Also -- to right-click (using the keypad), press the minus key and then the 5.  Again -- there is no need to hold down the minus key.  Just press each key separately.]